# Kuryłowicz on cases and prepositions

Tags: cases, morphosyntax, dependency-grammar

I've read Kuryłowicz's classic paper "Le problème du classement des cas" and I'm not sure how to interpret what he says about the difference between case affixes and prepositions. Does he in effect say that there's no functional difference between cases and prepositions? (So in a sentence like "I live in Beirut" are there only three functional units?)

Comment: Care to cite the passage? It doesn't seem to be readily available online.